# Normalize column in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to max/min normalize the `pageviews` for each `page` in a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
page                days since publishing   pageviews   
example.com/a       1                       5000
example.com/a       2                       10000
example.com/a       3                       7500
example.com/b       1                       10000
example.com/b       2                       20000
example.com/b       3                       15000
```

I'd like to produce something like:

```
page                days since publishing   pageviews   
example.com/a       1                       0
example.com/a       2                       1
example.com/a       3                       0.5
example.com/b       1                       0
example.com/b       2                       1
example.com/b       3                       0.5
```

The dataset is about 100 000 rows. Any help getting this done effectively would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('input.csv'))
b = a.groupby('page').min()
b.reset_index(inplace=True)
a = pd.merge(a,b,how='left',right_on = 'page',left_on = 'page')
a['minmaxscale'] = (a.pageviews_x-a.pageviews_y)/a.pageviews_y
```

produces

```
            page  days since publishing_x  pageviews_x  \
0  example.com/a                        1         5000   
1  example.com/a                        2        10000   
2  example.com/a                        3         7500   
3  example.com/b                        1        10000   
4  example.com/b                        2        20000   
5  example.com/b                        3        15000   

   days since publishing_y  pageviews_y  minmaxscale  
0                        1         5000          0.0  
1                        1         5000          1.0  
2                        1         5000          0.5  
3                        1        10000          0.0  
4                        1        10000          1.0  
5                        1        10000          0.5
```